# How to compute clock cycle time from given frequency

Tags: frequency, clock, clock-speed

let's say I have a processor runs at 100MHZ frequency how can I compute from this it's clock time for each cycle?
I know that Frequency = 1 / Clock Time but I am having trouble to fully understand how to manually convert it for example, to a nanosecond, given the frequency.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \text{Frequency} = \frac{1} { \text{Clock time} } $$
 or
$$ \text{Clock time} = \frac{1} { \text{Frequency} } $$

$$ \text{Clock time} = \frac{1} { \text{Frequency} } = \frac{1} { 100 \text{ MHz} } $$

$$ = \frac{1}{ (1 \cdot 10^2 \cdot 10^6) \text{ Hz} } = \frac{1}{ (1 \cdot 10^8) \text{ Hz} } = 1 \cdot 10^{-8} \text{ s} = 1 \cdot 10^1 \cdot 10^{-9} s = 10 \text{ ns} $$

Comment: so if i understand second = HZ?

Comment: @omrib40 no, \$ 1 \text{ Hz} = \frac{1}{1 \text{ second}} \$

Comment: much appreciated thanks!